# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') [JS]

Tags: javascript, html, css

expected outcome: div "test" should be shown,

but error in console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

It already worked in the past but somehow it stopped working (I guess it stopped when splitting html, css and js in different files but im not sure)

**My simplified source code:**

*index.html*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<script src="./main.js"></script>
<div id="test"> test </div>
```

*main.css*

```
#test{display: none}
```

*main.js*

```
 //(agree not defined so typeof(agree) == undefined)
 if (agree == undefined) { document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block"; }
```

what did I do wrong? or is it actualy the splitted file / external js/css

Comment: Add `defer` into the script tag should help, I think. `<script defer src="./main.js"></script>`

Comment: Could you try moving ```<script src="./main.js"></script>``` after div tag? So that script will be the last loaded one.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan thank you, your Idea should also work, it was a problem while loading the script, the other solution is cleaner but yours also works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use one of the methods:

1. Add defer attribute

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<script defer src="./main.js"></script>
<div id="test"> test </div>
```

2. Add script after `div`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<div id="test"> test </div>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```